# How to determine image size like pinterest on URL fetch using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, pinterest, image-size

I am creating a web page that will let users input a URL and extract images from the URL, something like Facebook or pinterest and thefancy.com does. You input a URL and they fetch you image having width greater than a specified width.

My code was all jQuery without this requirement of image size determination and working fine.I should also say that  my javascript knowledge is pretty limited.

When user hits enter, the page issues an ajax request (using jQuery) to a server side script and receives a json object containing an array of image sources extracted from the page. inside ajax.success callback, I pass this array of images to a method that adds the images dynamically to a DIV using jquery append() method.

```
  // server script errors are also reported inside 
                    // ajax success callback
                    success: function(response){
                        switch(response.code) {
                            case 401 :
                                webgloo.sc.ImageSelector.showMessage(response.message,{"css":"color-red"});
                                break ;
                            case 200 :
                                webgloo.sc.ImageSelector.processUrlFetch(response);
                                break ;
                            default:
                                webgloo.sc.ImageSelector.showMessage(response.message,{"css":"color-red"});
                                break ;
                        }
                    },
```

I am stuck trying to get  image size inside the success callback handler. After reading on SO, I added an image load handler and inside that image load handler, I have a callback addImage() that increments a num_added variable. Later on I want to use this num_added
variable to determine what kind of message to show to user.

problem is that showNextMessage() does not wait for the loop to be completed in processUrlFetch(). showNextMessage() is fired as soon as processUrlFetch() is called. Hence I always show the "No Images found" message.

I have tried researching the topic but I am out of my depth here.  I think mixing jquery and DOM events may be an issue. Also, I am not  sure how bulletproof my methodology to get image size via image.load() is. I also do not know if imagesloaded plugin will help my cause.

I have two questions

1. if what I am doing to  get "real" image size for dynamically
   inserted images here is a valid cross browser technique (relying on
   img.load event)
2. How can I ensure that the showNextMessage() is only
   fired after the loop  is finished?

processsUrlFetch : function(response) {
                var images = response.images ;

```
            for(i = 0 ; i < images.length ; i++) {
                var img = new Image();
                /* trouble part */
                img.onload = function() {
                    if((this.width >= 300) && (this.height >= 300 )) {
                        webgloo.sc.ImageSelector.addImage(this.src);
                    }

                }

                img.src = images[i] ;
                webgloo.imagep.src = images[i] ;
            }

            webgloo.sc.ImageSelector.showNextMessage();
        },



        showNextMessage : function() {

            if(webgloo.sc.ImageSelector.num_added > 0 ) {
                $("#stack").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#next-message").fadeIn("slow");
            } else {
                var message = "No image of appropriate size found!"; 
                webgloo.sc.ImageSelector.showMessage(message, {"css":"color-red comment-text"});
            }

        },

        addImage : function(image) {
            webgloo.sc.ImageSelector.num_added++ ;
            var index = webgloo.sc.ImageSelector.num_added ;

            if(webgloo.sc.ImageSelector.debug) {
                console.log("Adding image : " + index + " : " + image);
            }

            var buffer = this.imageDiv.supplant({"srcImage":image, "id":index } );
            // logo, small icons etc. are first images in a page
            // what we are interested in will only come later.
            $("div#stack .images").prepend(buffer);

            this.bucket[index] = { "id":index, "srcImage": image, "selected" : false} ;

        },
```

---

If you want to look at full code - Here is the gist :- https://gist.github.com/3084904

Comment: This is probably not super helpful, but if your calling a server side script, why not return back the image size from the server? (this is easy in PHP - not sure the language you are using)

Comment: @Applehat performance reason. I do not want to peek/open 20 URL doing what can be done on client side. The gist has my PHP script.  server script is loading DOM of page and that itself is expensive operation, especially for huge pages.

Answer (score 0):

As far as having a reliable way of getting the image dimensions, if you make them DOM elements (e.g. in an img tag) you should be able to get the true height and width of the element containing the image using the jQuery.actual plugin.  Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question.

Source here: https://github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.actual/
Demo here: http://dreamerslab.com/demos/get-hidden-element-width-with-jquery-actual-plugin

As for showNextMessage being called only once and at the proper time, I don't have a solid answer for you, but perhaps you could move the call to webgloo.sc.ImageSelector.showNextMessage() to a callback that is attached to the image load that finishes last.